# How to get the right 'type ' in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

this is my code：every request function used the same code snippet'Alamofire.request........'

```
    import Alamofire
    import AlamofireObjectMapper

    //so many functions like this to wrapper  different json 'RecommadnBannerObject','RecommadnPostObject'...

    func requestDataForBanner(completionHandler: (banner: Result<RecommadnBannerObject>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(NGAApi.Router.Bannerrecm).responseObject { (response:Response<RecommadnBannerObject, NSError>) in
        guard let model = response.result.value else {
            print("Error RecommadnBannerObject")
            completionHandler(banner: Result.Failure(response.result.error!))
            return
        }
        completionHandler(banner: Result.Success(model) )
    }
}
```

so i defined a function

```
static func sendRequestWithRouter<T>(router:URLRequestConvertible, classType: T.Type, completionHandler: (items: Result<T> ) -> Void ){
    
    Alamofire.request(router).responseObject { (response:Response<classType, NSError>->Void) in
     //do something
    }

}
```

but the xcode tells me that 'classType is not a type'.

[the documents says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of that type followed by .Type.

so what should i do..

Comment: `Alamofire.request(router).responseObject { (response:Response<T, NSError>->Void) in
     //do something
    }`
dose not wok either

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Alamo fire but can you just use `T` instead of `T.Type`?

`T.Type` will not give the type itself but a representation that can be accessed at runtime. I would ask what the purpose of the argument classType is? In any given use of the function T itself will be available and usable at compile time so it doesn't need to be passed it.

Comment: i tried that but the xcode raise another error ` Cannot convert value of type '(Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> ()' to expected argument type 'Response<_, NSError> -> Void'`